# How to track searches in piwik?

Tags: analytics, matomo

The site I'm building has a jquery based search input that hides or shows elements that match whatever you type in:
http://pieline.net/

There's no submit button - results are displayed in real time.
Is there any way to track what users are typing into this box? Something to do with custom variables maybe?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what we do on [Piwik's developer site](http://developer.piwik.org/) to track searches:

```
_paq.push(['trackSiteSearch', 'here is the search query', false, false]);
```

This is pretty straightforward, have a look at [the "Internal search tracking" documentation](http://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide#internal-search-tracking) too.